# htaccess to give friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm dealing with a noobish problem but i quite dont understand the way that htaccess works.

So i have a link

```
http://example.com/user/profile.php?username=1
```

And with this rewrite rule i make it more userfriendly

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

And it makes the link like this

```
http://example.com/user/1
```

All good until know.
So my question is that if in the 1st link i DONT give the Name of the username is there anyway that htaccess to make it appear on the link?

If i click the following

`<a href="http://example.com/user/profile.php?username=1">see my profile</a>`

The htaccess should make the link

```
http://example.com/user/Konstantinos-Natsios/
```

So can this happen? and if yes is there any example?

FYI in the profile.php?username=1
with php i take the "1" and i make a query at my DB to get the user's name email etc.

Comment: Nope. You need to fix your PHP script to do the database lookup and name->id mapping. Or perform the redirect on detecing `$_GET["id"]` requests / or a `HTTP_REDIRECT_URL` etc. (You also need `[\w-]+` as placeholder instead of `[a-z0-9]` of course.)

Comment: @mario ok i thought this could be the answer. You think it would be a good idea to have unique usernames and to search through them and NOT through ID's?

Comment: It depends on your traffic.

Comment: @hjpotter92 in which question you reffer ?

Comment: Definitely. You should prefer usernames in URLs instead of leaking database-internal IDs (which are rarely user-friendly / SEO compliant). -- Note: theoretically there is a way to let `.htacceess` handle the id->name redirects/rewrites using `RewriteMap`s, but Apache cannot utilize your database as easily.